# Expand All / Collapse All

Tags: javascript, html

I have about 13 HTMLItems which looks like this:

html script 1

```
<HTMLItem><staticValue>
<input type="BUTTON" class="clsPromptButton" onClick="JavaScript:ShowHide(&quot;HomeTown&quot;)" value="Home Town or City" 
style="color:  #4e86c2;  font: 14px Ariel; font-weight:Bold; text-align:left;height:20px;border:0pt solid #FFFFFF">
</staticValue></HTMLItem>
```

html script 2

```
<span id = "HomeTown">
```

html script 3

```
</span>
```

and they are all defined by this:

```
<script language="javascript">

function HideStartup()
{
    var p1 = document.getElementById("EmpOrg");
    var p2 = document.getElementById("CertType");
    var p3 = document.getElementById("PrevClients");
    var p4 = document.getElementById("LLCourse");
    var p5 = document.getElementById("ProfInt");
    var p6 = document.getElementById("ProfMem");
    var p7 = document.getElementById("ProfRef");
    var p8 = document.getElementById("ProjExp");
    var p9 = document.getElementById("Quali");
    var p10 = document.getElementById("SecExp");
    var p11 = document.getElementById("HomeTown");
    var p12 = document.getElementById("WorkAS");


    p1.style.display = 'none';
    p2.style.display = 'none';
    p3.style.display = 'none';
    p4.style.display = 'none';
    p5.style.display = 'none';
    p6.style.display = 'none';
    p7.style.display = 'none';
    p8.style.display = 'none';
    p9.style.display = 'none';
    p10.style.display = 'none';
    p11.style.display = 'none';
    p12.style.display = 'none'

}

HideStartup()

function ShowHide(prompt)
{
    var ps = document.getElementById(prompt);

    if (ps.style.display != 'none' )
    {   
        ps.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {           ps.style.display = '';
                        }

}


</script>
```

---> So they are all scripted to SHOW/HIDE sections one by one as I click on the heading names.... BUT I want a button, well 2 buttons, which acts as Expand All, and Collapse All to use, how to I do this?

Comment: I assume by "Expand All" you mean show all? Your function `HideStartup()` already does hide all, so just add another function that shows all.

Comment: Hi, well at the moment I have to click on each individual "header" of which there are 12, and inside these headers are prompt boxes which I have created in Cognos report studio. But I want a button that I can click on to expand (show) all of the sections at once, and again to Collapse (hide) all of them again at once.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the Buttons have the `clsPromptButton` class. You could use the following code:

At the top of your Script tags put, `window.toggleAll = 0;`
then put the following somewhere:

```
function toggleAll() {

var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.clsPromptButton'));

    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
        // Swap each element between display 'none' and 'block'
        if (window.toggleAll === 0) {
            button.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            button.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Swap window.toggleAll between 0 and 1
        window.toggleAll = window.toggleAll === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    });
}
```

Then somewhere on your page, put a button which calls the `toggleAll` function.

I would however recommend looking into the Revealing Module pattern design pattern, so you can better encapsulate your code and not have your code in the global namespace. You might not need to worry about that at the moment though :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your suggestion. It helps to say that I know nothing of HTML or JAVASCRIPT or similar, I am a report author and have done these with help from my friend Google so far, so forgive me, but where excatly is the "top of my script tags" ? Thanks!

Comment: By at the top of your script tag I mean this line:

`<script language="javascript">`

Put the `window.toggleAll = 0;` just below that line :)

Comment: :) Thank you! Would the toggle all button look like this? <HTMLItem><staticValue>
<input type="BUTTON" class="clsPromptButton" onClick="JavaScript:ToggleAll()" value="Expand/Collapse All" 
style="color:  #4e86c2;  font: bold 12px Arial;width:100px;height:29px;border: 1px solid #4e86c2">
</staticValue></HTMLItem>

Comment: I get this very unhelpful error when running my report: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Mon, 12 May 2014 14:28:33 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 121
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://ausyd01mt651/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll

Comment: Ummmm. Try:
<HTMLItem><staticValue> <input type="BUTTON" onClick="JavaScript:toggleAll()" value="Expand/Collapse All" style="color: #4e86c2; font: bold 12px Arial;width:100px;height:29px;border: 1px solid #4e86c2"> </staticValue></HTMLItem>

Comment: I still get an error, I might have the script in the wrong place or something, I'm not sure, but I can't worry about this too much now because I have so many other things I need to do as well so I will revisit this again when I have some more time towards the end of the week, I just thought this would be something I could do quickly, but clearly my very limited knowledge of the language is not helping me at all :) thanks for your help.